# Accessing layers of SpatRaster objects stored in memory

Tags: r, terra

I am using the R terra package and have some questions about the difference between storing SpatRaster objects in memory versus storing them in a file. Admittedly I'm a bit naive about this but my understanding is that reading rasters into memory makes many raster operations (e.g., `terra::extract`) much faster. So this is what I've been doing (using `r@ptr$readAll()` if `r` is my SpatRaster object). However I have now noticed something with respect to "memory" vs. "from a file" for SpatRaster objects with multiple layers. I can demonstrate this with a short example:

```
require(terra)
require(microbenchmark)

# Make a random raster; doesn't really matter what the values are, just has to be fairly big and have multiple layers. By default (at least on my device) this raster's source appears to be "memory".
r_from_memory = rast(nrow = 5000, ncol = 5000, nlyrs = 3, vals = runif(3 * 5000^2))

# write the raster to a file and read it back in; this gives us two equal SpatRasters with different sources
writeRaster(r_from_memory, "r_test.tif")
r_from_file = rast("r_test.tif")

# Access the first layer of the SpatRaster. r_from_memory[[1]] takes almost 100x as long on my device.
bench = microbenchmark(r_from_memory[[1]], r_from_file[[1]], times = 50)
```

On my device (Windows 11 x64; R 4.3.2; terra 1.7-55), getting the first layer of `r_from_memory` takes almost 100 times as long as `r_from_file`.

[image]

This factor is even larger on a remote device I have access to that runs Ubuntu 18.04.6. The versions of R (4.3.0) and terra (1.7-23) are slightly older, because I don't have admin privileges and can't update them all the time, but over there it takes almost 300x as long to get the first layer of `r_from_memory`.

For additional context, the reason this is relevant to me is because I'm trying to write an R function that has a big loop and inside the loop does the following things: a) subsets a SpatRaster object given as a function argument to get one layer, where the layer index depends on but is not equal to the loop iteration, and b) use `extract` to get the value of that raster at a bunch of coordinates, which are different each time the loop iterates. The solution I have come up with so far is to just extract from the entire raster, with all layers, and take the layer I want as a subset afterwards, which honestly works fine, but I am still interested in if there is an easier / faster way to subset these rasters that have been read into memory. Or, more generally, any extra information about rasters written to files vs. in memory would be interesting for me to hear about.

Thanks in advance to anyone who has any thoughts about this, and let me know if I need to provide additional information!

Comment: You're measuring two different operations, your 'in memory' both creates and reports metadata from the raster, 'from file' merely reports metadata. These are milliseconds, and it takes the average observer 250 ms to register a visual scene has changed, but `for` loops see better quicker. Ideally you only want in memory what's sufficient to task per iteration and this can be controlled via indexing (per interation) on the rasters, as arrays [hadley -subsetting](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/subsetting.html), Benchmark the approaches and what makes sense to you and your processing pipeline.